# Calling dynamic PSObject Properties in C# returns RuntimeBinderException

Tags: c#, powershell, dynamic, active-directory

I have integrated a PowerShell script in my C# code and I invoke it using C#.

What the script does is it gets some groups and their members from *Active Directory* and returns them in my C# code as a *PSObject*. This object has a property called "Member" which contains an *Array* of members that the group contains. Each of these members has other properties such as EmailAddress, Name etc. which I added via PowerShell and I also tested the script, it works as intended.

Here is my code in C# where I try to get the group members using a dynamic variable:

```
GetGroupMembers(PSObject groupObject) {
    // These are the group members, an object Array with 4 objects gets returned
    dynamic members = groupObject.Properties["Member"].Value;

    foreach (var member in members) {
        string objectClass = member.ObjectClass;
        ADObject memberObject;

        switch (objectClass) {
            case "user":
                // This is where the exception gets thrown, since the "EmailAddress" value is null
                string email = member.Properties["EmailAddress"].Value.ToString();
            [...]
```

The problem here is that while debugging, I can actually see that the property is there in the dynamic **members** variable, but it gets removed in the **member** variable during the foreach loop.
[Here's a screenshot I made during debugging, which shows clearly that the property is available in the **members** variable.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjKCj.png)

The exception which I get is a RuntimeBinderException with the message "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference"
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String )
        at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)

Maybe the error is clear but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Would really appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Your screenshot only show that property exists. There is no evidence that property actually have not null value. You need to split your command to know where exactly exception occurs: `PSPropertyInfo property=member.Properties["EmailAddress"]; object value=property.Value; string email=value.ToString();`.

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks for the answer. The problem is that `member.Properties["EmailAddress"]` is actually `null`, and before the foreach loop I can see that the property at least exists (as you mentioned based on the screenshot), and that's the strange thing, somehow it gets lost... I get a RuntimeBinderException when adding the statement mentioned from you: `PSPropertyInfo property = member.Properties["EmailAddress"]; `

Comment: `string email = member.EmailAddress;`

Comment: That returns null... but no exception...  [Here](http://i.imgur.com/V9rgeWr.png) is a screenshot of the **member** variable during debugging, under properties there don't seem to be any properties in the Results view, which explains why it's null but not why it's somehow gone whereas before it was there...

Comment: btw. the user (member) does have an E-Mail address and I can see the value while debugging but only in the **members** variable and not in **member** :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. I didn't use the `dynamic` type at all, this is how I solved it if anyone is still looking for a solution:

```
GetGroupMembers(PSObject groupObject) {
        object membersValue = groupObject.Properties["Member"].Value;
        object[] members;

        // Does the group have any members?
        if (membersValue == null)
            return null;

        // If the group has only one member, then it won't be an object array but rather a PSObject
        if (membersValue.GetType() == typeof(PSObject))
        {
            members = new object[] {membersValue};
        }
        else
        {
            // The group has more than one member, in this case we can cast it to an object array
            members = ((object[])membersValue);
        }

        // use PSObject to access the object's properties
        foreach (PSObject member in members)
        {
            string objectClass = member.Properties["ObjectClass"].Value.ToString();
            Guid objectGuid = new Guid (member.Properties["objectGuid"].Value.ToString());

            ADObject memberObject;

            switch (objectClass)
            {
                case "user":
                    // You might want to check for null here as well before getting the values from these properties
                    string givenName = member.Properties["GivenName"].Value.ToString();
                    string surname = member.Properties["Surname"].Value.ToString();
                    string displayName = member.Properties["DisplayName"].Value.ToString();
                    [...]
```